# grails reload classes runtime

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I started to modify a grails application created from someone else. I can't understand why when I try to use *run-app* and I modify a controller, grails won't reload it at runtime. I have to stop and restart it, this is very frustrating.
I'm using the normal *development* environment.
OS Ubuntu 11.10, Grails 2.0.1
Can someone help me undestand why?

Cheers

Comment: and what OS? My magical crystal ball tells me you're using Windows :)

Comment: nono I don't want to die trying to program on windows ;)
ubuntu 11.10 and grails 2.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Eclipse (STS), when you modify the class from there but execute the run-app from console it will not reload, it was just execute run-app from eclipse